# How to handle returned value if an exception happens in a library code

Tags: python, exception

There is a lib code, trying to parse an Element Tree object. If exception happens, it either returns an empty dict of dict or a partially constructed object of such type. In this case, caller needs to parse the results to see if parsing is correctly handled or not. Or in other words, the returned dict is not deterministic. How to solve this issue? Or if this is an issue?

```
def parse_ET(self, ETObj):
    if ETObj == None: return None
    dict_of_dict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    try:
        for doc in ETObj.iter("result"):
            id = doc.attrib.get("id")
            for elem in doc.iter("attrib"):
                dict_of_dict[id].setdefault(elem.attrib.get("name"), elem.text)
    except Exception, ex:
        logging.exception("%s:%s" % (self.__class__, str(ex)))
    finally:
        return dict_of_docs
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def parse_ET(self, ETObj):
```

Python style guide recommends lowercase_with_underscores for both function and parameter names

```
    if ETObj == None: return None
```

Use `is None` to check for None. However, consider whether you really want to support None as a parameter. Why would someone pass None to this function? Do they really want a None in return?

```
    dict_of_dict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
```

Avoid names that describe the datastructure. Choose names that describe what you are putting in it.

```
    try:
        for doc in ETObj.iter("result"):
            id = doc.attrib.get("id")
            for elem in doc.iter("attrib"):
                dict_of_dict[id].setdefault(elem.attrib.get("name"), elem.text)
```

Can there be duplicate "id" and "name"? If not you don't need to use defaultdict or setdefault

```
    except Exception, ex:
```

You should almost never catch generic exceptions. Only catch the actual exceptions you want.

```
        logging.exception("%s:%s" % (self.__class__, str(ex)))
```

Don't log errors and try to continue on as if nothing has happened. If your function fails, it should raise an exception. In this case, you probably shouldn't even catch the exception.

```
    finally:
        return dict_of_docs
```

`finally` is for cleanup tasks. Under no circumstances should you putting a return in it.

Comment: Thanks Winston. If I don't want to catch the exception, the best way is to remove try...except? or just raise?

Comment: What's the best way to force argument not None?  <br>>>> def func(a):
...     print a

Comment: @user24622, if the caller caused the error, then you should raise a new error which tells the caller what they did wrong. If its a bug in your code, just don't catch it.

Comment: @user24622, as for forcing not None, don't bother. You'll get an fairly obvious error in any case, so you don't gain anything by checking. You can't assume that its safe to pass None into things, and so you don't need to let your callers assume that.